# Multi-index a pandas dataframe with values from a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
column1   column2   column3   column4
P1        D1        T1        1.0
P1        D1        T2        2.0
P1        D2        T1        3.0
P1        D2        T2        4.0
P2        D1        T1        5.0
P2        D1        T2        6.0
P2        D2        T1        7.0
P2        D2        T2        8.0
```

And I would like to multi-index the columns by the value in the column2 and column3. It should look like this

```
column1   column4
          D1                  D2
          T1        T2        T1        T2
P1        1.0       2.0       3.0       4.0
P2        5.0       6.0       7.0       8.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['column1','column2','column3'])['column4'].unstack([1,2])
print (df)
column2   D1        D2     
column3   T1   T2   T1   T2
column1                    
P1       1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
P2       5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```

If need top level of `MultiIndex` by `column4` remove `column4` and use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['column1','column2','column3']).unstack([1,2])
print (df)
        column4               
column2      D1        D2     
column3      T1   T2   T1   T2
column1                       
P1          1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
P2          5.0  6.0  7.0  8.0
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed and I wish I have asked the question 3 hours ago when I started trying multiindex and groupby without any success!